# Is it the right code in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to Assembly and reading about calling convention in x86 .

In one of the example below .

```
cdecl int MyFunction1(int a, int b)
{
 return a + b;
}


 x = MyFunction1(2, 3);


_MyFunction1:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, [ebp + 8]
mov edx, [ebp + 12]
add eax, edx
pop ebp
ret

push 3
push 2
call _MyFunction1
add esp, 8
```

I am able to understand most part of the given code but have doubt on one line where pop ebp has been done.

I think right call will be "pop [ebp+4]" because after push ebp , mov ebp ,esp is performed which cause ebp pointer to decremented by 4 and hence to reach to original position have to add 4 bytes to ebp.

Comment: xen-0 answer is correct, but you don't even need e full prologue/epilogue (you are not using stack instructions in your body, so no need to restore esp wit a mov)
In general, you usually need the mov only if you are making space for locals with a sub in the prologue

Answer (score 3):

The typical epilogue reads:

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

The old ebp is stored at the address your current ebp is pointing to. Hence `mov esp, ebp` puts the stack pointer at this address, so `pop ebp` will restore ebp correctly (and esp).

It so happens that you can forgo the `mov esp, ebp` instruction in your function, since you never use the stack and ebp and esp already point to the same address.

`pop [ebp+4]` would be incorrect, since that would put the value at the top of the stack into `[ebp+4]`

Comment: I do not even think pop [ebp+4] is legal in x86 assembly.. those are two indirect (memory) accesses, if I am not wrong..

Comment: I thought the same and my original answer reflected that, but Google results and a quick test said otherwise.

Comment: pop [ebp+4] reads a value from [esp] and then writes it in the memory at the address [ebp+4]. It is different from "pop ebp" which reads a value from [esp] and writes it to the register ebp.

Answer (score 0):

```
push ebp
la la la la la la la la la la 
pop ebp
ret
```

So it's fine.

One push

One pop